# Can we prioritise display of UIPopOverController to up or down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIButton` in my app. On clicking of `UIButton`, it displays the `UIPopoverController`. Now I want that all the time `UIPopOverController` is displayed beneath the `UIButton`, except there is no enough space below `UIButton`. How can I achieve this?

I tried following code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button frame]
                                               inView:self.view
                             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                             animated:YES];
}
```

However this displays the `UIPopOverController` to the right side of the `UIButton`, and if there is no enough space on the right side then it displays above the UIButton.

I want it to always display the below `UIButton` and in the case where it is not possible then above the `UIButton`.

I even tried

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[button frame]
                                               inView:self.view
                             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown | UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                             animated:YES];
}
```

However, it always displays the `UIPopOverController` above the `UIButton`.

Is there any way where I can tell `UIPopOverController` to prioritise to down?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `[self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
                    inView:sender
  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                  animated:YES];`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I had tried this. This displays the UIPopOverController to the right side of the button. I want it to be at the bottom of UIButton.

Comment: Its not same as you have tried. see this `inView:sender ` you have used `inView:self.view`

Comment: Also that may be helpful for you : https://github.com/soberman/ARSPopover

Comment: If we use [button bounds], it will always display the popover on top left corner of the screen.

Comment: can you share the image of your screen where button is placed in screes?

Comment: @PiyushPatel: I doubt I could share the screenshot. However I would try to explain the screen design. Actually the UIButton is to left side of the iPad. The UIButton has UIView above it. The UIView height is flexible depending on the content.

Comment: It means Button is at like `leftBarButtonItem` of Navigation bar?

Comment: No no. Its not on the navigation bar. Its on the iPad. Below the UIView.

Comment: I cant figure out where it is. Below UIView as you said but  Which UIView and where Below at bottom of screen ?. Then The UIButton has UIView above it  that means you have aded UIView as a subview of button?

Comment: So there is UIView which covers almost half of the iPad screen. There are contents (subviews) in the UIView which decides the height of UIView. Below this UIView, there is the button; clicking on which displays UIPopOverController.